# Reduce Freeswitch video conference latency

Tags: webrtc, latency, freeswitch, video-conferencing

We're experimenting with a Freeswitch based multiparty video conferencing solution (Zoom like). The users are connecting via WebRTC (Verto clients) and the streams are all muxed and displayed on the canvas (mod_conference in mux mode). It works OK, but we notice high media latency for mixed output and this makes it very difficult to have a real-time dialogue. This is not load related, even with only 1 caller watching himself on the canvas (the mux conference output), it takes almost 1 second to see a local move being reflected on the screen (e.g. if I raise my hand I can see it happening on the screen after almost 1 second ). This is obviously the roundtrip delay, but after discarding the intrinsic network latency (measured to be about 100 ms roundtrip) there seem to be around 800-900 ms added latency. There's no TURN relaying involved. It seems this is being introduced along the buffering/ transcoding/ muxing pipeline. Any suggestions please what to try to reduce the latency? What sort of latency should we expect, what's your experience, has anyone deployed a Freeswitch video conferencing with acceptable latency for bidirectional, real time conversations? Ultimately I'm  trying to understand if Freeswitch can be used for a multiparty real time video conversation or I should give up look for something else. Thanks!